# ReactJS - updating state array causes undefined in a different component

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a rather complex React app.  I have a modal with a form and a submit button.  The form has a submit handler attached that runs some code.  Part of that code is updating the orders state array with the new data from the form.  When that happens, the page errors out with a different component that uses the orders state array stating it is `undefined`.  I'm not sure if I'm updating the state incorrectly or if I have something else wrong in my app.  I am passing orders and setOrders down as props to the respective components.

Here is the modal component that is trying to update the state array.  SetOrders gets passed down as a prop:

```
import ReactModal from 'react-modal';
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import CloseButton from './CloseButton';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';
import { RadioGroup, Radio } from 'react-radio-group';

const initialState = {
    bagID: '',
    lineTechName: '',
    infoCorrect: '',
    materialCorrect: '',
    unwantedMaterials: '',
    unwantedMaterial: '',
    qualityAcceptable: '',
    program: 'Windows',
    sealingProperly: '',
    temperature: ''
};

const PackagerModal = (props) => {
    const {
        openPackager,
        activeOrder,
        setOrders,
        setOpenPackager,
        customStyles,
        setPackagerChecklistResults
    } = props;

    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useReducer(
        (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }),
        initialState
    );

    const handleTextChange = (evt) => {
        const { name, value } = evt.target;
        setUserInput({ [name]: value });
    };

    const handleRadioChange = (val, name) => {
        setUserInput({ [name]: val });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();

        // do database stuff
        // save to state for now
        // save form data to the packager checklist results state variable
        setPackagerChecklistResults(userInput);

        // create a new temp order so we don't mutate state and set the
        // packagerChecked field to true for this order
        const tempActiveOrder = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(activeOrder));
        tempActiveOrder.packagerChecked = true;
        tempActiveOrder.packagerChecklist = userInput;
        console.log(tempActiveOrder);
        setOrders((prevOrders) => {
            prevOrders.map((order) => {
                return order.id === tempActiveOrder.id
                    ? tempActiveOrder
                    : order;
            });
        });

        // clear out form inputs
        setUserInput(initialState);

        // close package modal
        setOpenPackager(false);
    };

    return (
        <ReactModal
            isOpen={openPackager}
            style={customStyles}
            className={'order-details-modal'}
            closeTimeoutMS={1000}
        >
            <CloseButton setOpenModal={setOpenPackager} />
            <h2>Packager Order Checklist</h2>
            <Scrollbars autoHeight autoHeightMin={500} autoHeightMax={600}>
                <form className={'form'} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <!-- rest of the form inputs here are irrelavant -->
                    <input
                        className={'btn btn-primary d-block mx-auto mb-2'}
                        type={'submit'}
                        value={'Submit'}
                    />
                </form>
            </Scrollbars>
        </ReactModal>
    );
};

PackagerModal.propTypes = {
    openPackager: PropTypes.bool,
    setOpenPackager: PropTypes.func,
    customStyles: PropTypes.object,
    activeOrder: PropTypes.object,
    setPackagerChecklistResults: PropTypes.func
};

export default PackagerModal;
```

And here is the component that relies on the orders state array to show the orders on the page.  Orders gets passed down as a prop:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Order from '../order/Order';
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';
//import { ScheduleContext } from '../../schedule-context';
import '../../App.scss';

// border-right-width set below to fix an issue with doubled borders between columns
const MyOrder = styled.div`
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    background-color: ${(props) =>
        props.isDraggingOver ? '#fffbc9' : '#ffffff'};
    border-style: ${(props) =>
        props.isDraggingOver ? 'dashed' : 'solid'};
    border-right-width: ${(props) =>
        props.isDraggingOver ? '3px' : '0'};
`;
const OrderColumn = (props) => {
    const {
        columnId,
        line,
        setOpenLineModal,
        setLineModalHeader,
        orders
    } = props;
    //const orders = useContext(ScheduleContext).orders;
    console.log('orderCol orders: ', orders);
    const orderIDs = props.orderIDs;

    const openLineModal = () => {
        if ((line === 'middle' || line === 'last') && orderIDs.length) {
            setLineModalHeader(props.title + ' Orders');
            setOpenLineModal(true);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Droppable droppableId={columnId}>
            {(provided, snapshot) => {
                return (
                    <MyOrder
                        className={'col order-column ' + props.line}
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.droppableProps}
                        isDraggingOver={snapshot.isDraggingOver}
                        key={columnId}
                    >
                        <Scrollbars
                            // This will activate auto hide
                            autoHide
                            // Hide delay in ms
                            autoHideTimeout={1000}
                            // Duration for hide animation in ms.
                            autoHideDuration={200}
                        >
                            <h3
                                className={
                                    (line === 'middle' || line === 'last') &&
                                    orderIDs.length
                                        ? 'text-center title hand-cursor'
                                        : 'text-center title'
                                }
                                onClick={() => openLineModal()}
                            >
                                {props.title} <span>({orderIDs.length})</span>
                            </h3>
                            <div className={'orders'}>
                                {orderIDs &&
                                    orderIDs.map((orderID, index) => {
                                        const order = orders.find(
                                            (o) => o.id === orderID
                                        );

                                        return (
                                            <Order
                                                key={orderID}
                                                order={order}
                                                index={index}
                                            />
                                        );
                                    })}
                            </div>
                        </Scrollbars>
                        {provided.placeholder}
                    </MyOrder>
                );
            }}
        </Droppable>
    );
};

OrderColumn.propTypes = {
    orders: PropTypes.array,
    orderIDs: PropTypes.array,
    columnId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    line: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    setOpenLineModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    setLineModalHeader: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default OrderColumn;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to return your new mapped array in your `setOrders` function:

```
setOrders((prevOrders) => {
            // return this map
            return prevOrders.map((order) => {
                return order.id === tempActiveOrder.id
                    ? tempActiveOrder
                    : order;
            });
        });
```

Also, as an aside, I would create a new array like this: `const newArr = [...oldArr]` instead of using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` because JSON stringify and parse are more expensive, plus I think it looks cleaner, but personal preference is all.

Or, for an object:

```
const newObj = { ...oldObj }
```

Comment: I tried this: `const tempActiveOrder = [...activeOrder];` and get this: `TypeError: activeOrder is not iterable`

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it is an object.  I updated my answer

Comment: That was it!  Such a simple mistake, but I spent way too long on that one!  Thank you!